# ASP.Net MVC Submit Form Doesn't Find Method - Can't Use Vanilla Form?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form as follows:

```
<form action='@Url.Action("submitForm", "Home")'>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Details</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="authorisedCheckbox" value="Authorised" id="authCheck" />Authorised<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="enabledCheckbox" value="Enabled" id="eCheck" />Enabled<br />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="Save Changes">
    <button type="button">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

This calls a method in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult submitForm(string authorisedCheckbox, string enabledCheckbox)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("input values: ");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(authorisedCheckbox);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(enabledCheckbox);

       //some other processing will be done here

        return View();
    }
```

But when the button is hit, the form gives a 404 not found error. I have seen posts using @using (Html.BeginForm("method", "controller")) - is the only way to call into a controller method using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Is the action you're trying to call in a different area?

Comment: The default is GET. Specify `method="POST"`

Comment: An action named `submitForm` is not keeping with the RESTful philosophy of ASP.NET MVC. Consider keeping the same action name as your `GET` verb handler.

Comment: the method passing values to the view and the method I'm trying to call are on the same controller 'HomeController', so it should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stephen Muecke for pointing out the simple thing to do was add method='post' to the  tag.

The action is also used to reference the view, so I will change 'submitForm' into something more appropriate, as suggested by @Dai.